# What should be ideal resolution of images for converting image data to TFRecords file format?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, tensorflow, gpu

I have around 25000 images with resolution of 3200*1800/JPEG/RGB divided into 5 labels.

1). I am wondering what should be ideal pre-processing tasks I should complete on images. Does it include only resolution optimisation.

2). I have single GTX 960m GPU(4GB) in my machine with i7 6700HQ, 16GB RAM

3). I am using [build_image_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py) for building TFRecords.

Please provide steps so as to optimise GPU time.